# App working as expected in API 29, but not in API 33

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-communication-services

I've built a simple app that uses the Azure Communication Service to call the echo test account.

When I test the app in the emulator with virtual device using API 29, I can connect, hear a message, record my response, and hear it played back - all is good.

When I test the app in API 33, the app seem to connect to the service ok (I get status changes from the API from connecting, to ringing to connected), I can then see the mic icon show up briefly on the top right corner, but immediately closes and I don't hear anything on the "call"

I am struggling to find out what may be the cause or how to troubleshoot. looging at logcat, I can see the following (last message repeats continuously)-

[image]

I tried to look up the errors but couldn't find anything I understood. any thoughts on what it might be or how to troubleshoot further?

(this is my first time using Android Studio)

Comment: Just verifying, is the emulator and physical device running the same OS version? Any differences/errors in the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat)? Also is the device and emulator on the same network (i.e. PC is on VPN to a supported region, but local WiFi is not)?

Comment: Thank you @MorrisonChang - very good shout regarding OS version. it was not. emulator was 29, device is 33. when using emulator API 33 I get the same (wrong behaviour).
I also was not aware of  logact, so thanks fro that too. any idea what would cause the mic to close immediately in API 33?

Comment: Hopefully if the mic closes an exception is thrown and would be seen in the logcat. Posting that error/stacktrace may provide some direction as to what is going on. I would make sure that you have the latest Azure Communication Service SDK as Android API 33 did a [number of changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13) which might be related but also should be in any SDK notes/updates. Also a Android 13 device has [microphone toggle](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#mic-camera-toggles)

Comment: bang on @MorrisonChang - I was sure I was on the latest SDK, but I wasn't. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the helpful guidance from Morrison Chang in the comments I updated the Azure Communication Service SDK to version 2.2.0 and it now works on Android API 33 as well.